# How to run set up mvc website on local

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, localhost

I've got a web application for our office use only. In my office I've got 12 computer and want to install one pc and access via web browser from all computers. I can run web application on visual studio but couldn't find a proper way for all computers and kinda new in this area.

I would like to access on browser like "myapp.com" or localhost something else. Is that possible to give specific name and access even on mobile phones?

Thanks in advance for all suggestions.

Comment: Please check [Getting Started With IIS Host and Publish in MVC 5](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/getting-started-with-iis-host-and-publish-in-mvc-5/).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698.aspx

Comment: Dont use VS for serving, activate IIS. The wired network would be fairly easy, phones would need to networked in with DNS.

Comment: So after set up, can I access from all devices which connected to same network like localhost:xxxx/myapp ? And about sql?

Comment: @K.Iglesias also a good read http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can host your application using IIS. IIS can be setup in any machine.

> **Steps :**
>
> 1. Install IIS
> 2. Open IIS manager by entering `inetmgr` in Run(win+R)
> 3. Add website by browisng to its location to the published website location. (Hope you know how to publish a website in visual studio)
> 4. Edit the web config file to configure the sql server credentials(Sql db could be hosted separately or in the same machine)
> 5. Right click the website in IIS Manager and click start.
> 6. Click browse to view the website
> 7. You could either access the site by `localhost:portnumber` or by specifying `IP:port number` in settings of the website in IIS manager
> 8. You can access the website from mobile or external devices if you select public IP for your website. Incase you're connected to a local network, then the website could be accessed only from within your work place. Discuss with your network admin about exposing your server to public by providing a public IP address, if you're on local network.

Feel free to revert if you have more doubts.